# adding text into iframe with jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, iframe

I have an HtmlEditor from asp controltoolkit.
That creates an iframe with a couple things i need (bold letter, etc).
I need to add text to that iframe with jquery.
so long i have this.

```
$('#<%= tbDescripcionInsert.ClientID %>').contents().text(textoMercancia.substring(15, textoMercancia.length));
```

My problem is that the things im using from the editor (bold letter etc) disappear when i add the text from jquery.

What can it be?
What is the best way to add text into an iframe with jquery?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.

I found a way to solve this:

```
$('#<%= tbDescripcionInsert.ClientID %>_ctl02_ctl00').contents().children().children('body').html(textoMercancia.substring(15, textoMercancia.length));
```

this way i can access the exact part of the iframe where the information is supossed to be loaded.
hope this help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that

```
  .text('blahblah')
```

replaces the text so you must use

```
 .append('blahblah')
```

or some similar command

**EDIT**
seeing your post this might be more effective

```
  $('#<%= tbDescripcionInsert.ClientID %>').contents().find('body').append('blahblah')
```

Comment: hi mcgrailm, it doesn´t works because i have the same problem, it uses another portion of the iframe and not the one i need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle markup, not just text, use html() instead of text().

Comment: hi christian, it doesn´t works because i have the same problem, it uses another portion of the iframe and not the  one i need.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

> var d = $("#someFrame")[0].contentWindow.document; // contentWindow works in IE7 and FF
>   d.open(); d.close(); // must open and
>   close document object to start using
>   it!

// now start doing normal jQuery:

> $("body", d).append("ABC");

Comment: i don't think all that is necessary

Comment: didn't try it and don't know if it works but thank you anyway.